# Search INT value in VARCHAR Column

Tags: sql, select, int, range, varchar

this is my question:

I need to get a range of values from MyTable:

### MyTable

ID (INT)

ContractNumber (VARCHAR)

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ContractNumber >= 1000 AND ContractNumber <= 1999
```

All the values stored in MyTable (ContractNumber) are INTEGER Type.

How can i get this range of values?

Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE cast(ContractNumber as int) >= 1000 
AND cast(ContractNumber as int) <= 1999
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your varchar field to int, something like below works for PostgreSQL

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ContractNumber::int4 >= 1000 AND ContractNumber::int4 <= 1999
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot, i solved my problem using BETWEN, i also tried Cast and Convert but it didnt Work.

Thanks!!